# Azure CDN Purge REST request fails with error 400

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I am using Azure CDN for Akamai and noticing that it return 400 Error code with following message - "We can only accept 100 paths for purging concurrently. Please try again in a few minutes."

I have Logic App which is triggered when a new asset is uploaded in storage account. This error happens only for 50% of changes.

How do I handle this ? The retry policy on logic app does not trigger because it's 400 status code.

As per documentation it says 50 concurrent request at profile level. but my workload sends only 10 request and REST api process 5 request successfully.

Comment: I'm hitting the same issue in my CI/CD process.  I've attempted sleeping so far for as long as 20 minutes with no luck.

Comment: Update : I changed concurrency control to 1 in my logic app and no more 400 errors. I still want to find out answer that in my original request i was only sending 10 paths. so why the 100 path error ?

Comment: I'm finding the same problem with MSFT cdn, I sent purge for 1 path (/*) and there are 6 files cached, so assuming it breaks out purge all into the number of files that's 6. Far from 100, why the error?

Comment: FYI I've posted the question at MSFT, hope to get an answer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/399711/cdn-library-for-net-purge-badrequest-exception-onl.html